# Adding Smart Contract to Existing Native Coin

Tags: smart-contract, native

A native coin was created prior to smart contract functionality availability on the platform.  Originally, it was thought that the native coin functionality was enough.  But recently we determined that we might benefit more from using a smart contract.

Can we update a native coin to include a smart contract, or must we "cancel" the old coin, and reissue under the smart contract?  Also, would there be any issues with reusing the coin symbol if the coin is cancelled and reissued?

Lastly, are coin symbols unique or can there be multiples?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should be two separate questions so that searching works better.  Add smart-contract capability?  Coins symbols unique?

Comment: Are you using "coin" when you should be using "token"?